# ReferenceError with an object name that isn't defined

Tags: javascript, html, function, object, dom

I am trying to get this program to display in the DOM with the HTML - however, from the JavaScript console it is giving me this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: phoneBrand is not defined
    at test.js:74
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at getMatchingPlans (test.js:73)
    at test.js:104
```

I have tried to modify this in different ways such as redoing the object declaration however I am still having this problem. Info on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

```
const phones = [{
        name: "iPhone XS", brand: "Apple", cost: 43, data: "500MB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
    },
        {
            name: "iPhone 11", brand: "Apple", cost: 64, data: "90GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "Galaxy S10", brand: "Samsung", cost: 30, data: "20GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "Galaxy S10", brand: "Samsung", cost: 65, data: "Unlimited", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "Galaxy A10", brand: "Samsung", cost: 11.99, data: "500MB", minutes: 250, texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "Galaxy S9", brand: "Samsung", cost: 31, data: "20GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "StarTAC 130", brand: "Motorola", cost: 3, data: "0MB", minutes: 200, texts: 500
        },
        {
            name: "Pixel 3A", brand: "Google", cost: 23, data: "4GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "Xperia 10", brand: "Sony", cost: 30, data: "20GB", minutes: "Unlimited", texts: "Unlimited"
        },
        {
            name: "P30", brand: "Huawei", cost: 27.99, data: "500MB", minutes: 500, texts: "Unlimited"
        }];






    // Functions

    function getUserPreferences() {

        // These are asking the user for entry of the data into the system.
            const userPrompt = [
            {
                phoneBrand: prompt("Enter a brand name") 
            },

            {
                phoneCost: prompt("Enter a monthly cost") 
            },

            {
                phoneData: prompt("Enter the amount of data") 
            },

            {
                phoneMins: prompt("How many minutes?") 
            },

            {
                phoneTexts: prompt("How many texts?") 
            },



            ]

    }

    function getMatchingPlans() {

        // This is then filtering the object of phones to match what the user has entered into the system.

        const matchingPhones = phones.filter(function(phone) {
            if(phone.brand===phoneBrand && phone.cost.toString()<=phoneCost && phone.data<=phoneData && phone.minutes.toString()<=phoneMins && phone.texts.toString()<=phoneTexts) {
                    return true;
        }
         return false;

    })

    }

    function printResults() {

        // This is then displaying data in the system.

            const returnPhones = document.querySelector("#returnPhones");

            matchingPhones.forEach(function(phone) {

            const newList = document.createElement("ul");
            newList.textContent=phone.name;
            returnPhones.appendChild(newList);

    })


    }




    const userPrefs = getUserPreferences();
    const matchingPlans = getMatchingPlans(userPrefs);
    printResults(matchingPlans);
```

Comment: Well where is `phoneBrand` supposed to come from in that filter? It's not declared as a parameter.

Comment: It's supposed to be matching it to the user response in the getUserPreferences function.

Comment: How is it supposed to find it in there? The `getUserPreferences()` function creates an object as a local value, but it doesn't do anything with it or return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error message states, you are using `phoneBrand` identifier, which is not defined - it is not function parameter, not a variable.

You probably need to make it an argument of `getMatchingPlans` function, along with other identifiers used there: `phoneCost`, `phoneData`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

2 Errors:

1. you don't return `userPrompt` in `getUserPreferences` function, so after `const userPrefs = getUserPreferences();` `userPredfs` is still `undefined`.
2. you pass `userPrompt` to `getMatchingPlans(userPrefs)` but in `getMatchingPlans` declaration `function getMatchingPlans(){...}` you don't use this parameter.